# How can I access the last event in a MIDI file?

Tags: python, midi

Here is my code:

```
import midi
pattern = midi.read_midifile('midifile.mid')

for p in pattern:
    for event, lastEvent in zip(p[1:], p):
        if event.name == 'Note On' and lastEvent.name == 'Note On':
            if event.channel == 1:
                print(event.pitch, lastEvent.pitch)
```

So as an example, the first 5 pitches are `57, 45, 65, 53, 52`
Meaning I want

```
45, 57
65, 45
53, 65
52, 53
```

But the output of the code is

```
45, 57
53, 65
64, 52
50, 62
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In theory, the `zip` is correct. What is the output of `print([e.pitch for e in p if e.channel == 1 and e.name == 'Note On'])`?

Comment: That would be error: 'TrackNameEvent' object has no attribute 'channel'. This is because only events named 'Note On' or 'Note Off' have channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is if the `.name` attributes aren't all `'Note on'`

that means you're comparing event with the previous event, rather than the previous event where `event.name == 'Note on'`

maybe try:

```
import midi
pattern = midi.read_midifile('midifile.mid')

for p in pattern:
    previous_event = p[0]
    for event in p[1:]:
        if event.name == 'Note on':
            if event.channel == 1:
                print(event.pitch, previous_event.pitch)
                previous_event = event
```

What I'm trying to do is filter the events in p for only those with event.name == 'Note on' (although I'm sure there is any easier way to do that by redefining p with something like `p = [event for event in p if event.name == 'Note on']`

Incorperating that would mean something like:

```
import midi
pattern = midi.read_midifile('midifile.mid')

for p in pattern:
    p2 = [event for event in p if event.name == 'Note on'] # maybe should include and event.channel ==1 ?
    for event, lastEvent in zip(p2[1:], p2):
        if event.name == 'Note On' and lastEvent.name == 'Note On':
            if event.channel == 1:
                print(event.pitch, lastEvent.pitch)
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution returned nothing but the second one returned exactly what was needed!

Comment: oh yeah, I just realised that the if condition in the first would never be satisfied :P

Comment: @roncook - the second solution is a little redundant, (it checks 'note on' twice) and the filter step doesn't include checing that channel == 1, so watch out for that.